# Run a Java main class using its relative path? (Python)

Tags: java, python, subprocess, relative-path

I am using Python to execute the JVM for a specified Java class, like so:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("java MyJavaClass")
```

However, the Java class is not in the same directory as the Python script, so this does not work. It is in a `bin` directory two directories up.

So I was hoping it would be possible to do something like below, but it doesn't work:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("java ../../bin/MyJavaClass")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the working directory when that Python code runs? `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
output = subprocess.check_output("java MyJavaClass", cwd="../../bin/")
```

When running Java, the directory structure implies a package structure, so it is required to execute java from the correct directory (unless using classpath).

Comment: Accepted this answer since it keeps the "directory changing" in Python. Both good answers though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the classpath, like this:

```
java -classpath ../../bin MyJavaClass
```

Please note, that if your class belongs to a certain package, you have to use the FQN (Full Qualified Name):

```
java -classpath ../../bin my.package.MyJavaClass
```